# Graph Cuts on OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, point-clouds, disparity-mapping

I'm trying to use the cvFindStereoCorrespondenceGC() function on opencv for the implementation of the graph cuts algorithm to find more accurate disparities than when using BM. I don't have this function for some reason; did they get rid of it in opencv 2.4.5? How else can I implement graph cuts? Thanks.

Comment: The GC algorithm for disparity generation can be found in OpenCV 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes!The documentation of this is not available .If you want to implement in python using opencv,here is the [link](http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2011/11/computing-disparity-map-in-opencv.html).

Comment: The findstereocorrespondenceGC function is also missing in Python.

Comment: I works fine on my pc! I have obtained many disparity images using this function.